# Divisão de SUM() em SQL Developer

Tags: sql, sqldeveloper

Estamos executando o SELECT abaixo na intenção de entregar um percentual de diferença entre os somátorios **PRECO_UNITARIO** e **PRECO_TABELA**. Tentamos fazer isso da maneira mais simples, efetuando a divisão comum dentro do SELECT e atribuindo **DIFERENCA_PERCENTUAL**, mas o Sql Developer entrega o seguinte erro:

```
ORA-00904: "DIFERENCA_PERCENTUAL": identificador inválido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erro na linha: 14 Coluna: 68
```

Abaixo está o SELECT que estamos executando no SQL Developer:

```
SELECT
FAITEMPE.NF NOTA_FISCAL,
FAITEMPE.CD_EMPRESA COD_CLIENTE,
GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO NOME_CLIENTE,
SUM(FAITEMPE.PR_UNITARIO) AS PRECO_UNITARIO,
SUM(FAITEMPE.PR_ORIGINAL) AS PRECO_TABELA,
(PR_UNITARIO / PR_ORIGINAL) AS DIFERENCA_PERCENTUAL

FROM FAITEMPE, GEEMPRES
WHERE FAITEMPE.CD_EMPRESA = GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA
AND FAITEMPE.DT_ITEM BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND FAITEMPE.CONTROLE LIKE '16'

GROUP BY FAITEMPE.NF, FAITEMPE.CD_EMPRESA, GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO, DIFERENCA_PERCENTUAL
```

Encaminhamos também o resultado da consulta simples antes de incrementar essa **DIFERENCA_PERCENTUAL**:

[image: Resultado da consulta select sem a intenção de cálculo dessa diferenca_percentual]

Alguma sugestão melhor de como podemos extrair essa informação???

Comment: ( SUM(FAITEMPE.PR_UNITARIO) /SUM(FAITEMPE.PR_ORIGINAL) ) as

Comment: @Motta Funcionou bem aqui.
Obrigado man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publicando e melhorando esta solução

```
...
(CASE WHEN SUM(FAITEMPE.PR_ORIGINAL) <> 0 
       THEN ( SUM(FAITEMPE.PR_UNITARIO) /
              SUM(FAITEMPE.PR_ORIGINAL) ) 
 ELSE NULL END) as DIFERENCA_PERCENTUAL,
...
```

Sendo o CASE apenas para tratamento de erro.